# Convert Indonesian datum .prj file, so it can be used for Mapinfo

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

This is the projection file information:

```
PROJCS["TM3 49.1 by gistutorial.net",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",200000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",1500000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",109.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

How can I convert it for Mapinfo so that I can use the CRS?

Comment: Mapinfo does not natively use .prj.  What do you actually want to do? Import shapefiles or define the same projection than in the .prj file for some MapInfo data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the MapInfo style definitions for this projection you can use gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html with the mapinfo output.

```
gdalsrsinfo test.prj -o mapinfo
'Earth Projection 8, 104, "m", 109.5, 0, 0.9999, 200000, 1500000'
```

Comment: thank you, I has trried this and with little trial and error,its work.